# Using Chart.js and Ng2-Chart in Cumulocity

Tags: angular, npm, chart.js, ng2-charts, cumulocity

I am currently building an Angular application to be hosted on the Cumulocity IoT platform, and I am trying to use Chart.js to generate custom bar charts. This did not work at first, so I did a little digging and discovered the special node package, ng2-chart, developed to employ Chart.js with Angular.

As it happens, I installed the latest version of each dependency, but I soon encountered errors trying to build and serve the application, among which is `NG8002` that states:

```
Error: src/app/features/[..].component.html:81:17 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'legend' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'.
```

I did some research and found that this is likely due to the latest versions of Chart.js and ng2-chart being incompatible with my current development environment:

- `@angular/cli`: 14.2.12
- `npm`: 6.14.18
- `c8y/client`: 1016.0.324

Has anyone else encountered this problem? What versions of Chart.js and ng2-chart could I use for my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i leave you a small image of the versions compatible with ng2-chart and an installation guide

[image]

**Installation Guide**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-charts

Comment: Thank you. Is there a similar table that deals with Angular compatibility with chart.js?

Comment: In the installation link that I have given you, they show you how to install chartjs together with ng2. In step number 2